# Wifi issues on Lubuntu

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, lubuntu, acer

I'm having some issues with the last release of Lubuntu on my old pc (ACER TravelMate 2702WLMi).

The main problem is that I cannot connect to any wifi line. In the network panel in the application bar I can only see  Ethernet Network, while there's no Wifi connections.

I've searched through some forums and the only post that seemed to correspond to my problem is this [one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers?newreg=6ca4b3c5ba9f4721830ec13120d0ca21).

The problem is that probably I don't have a Broadcom card but a Realtek one, but I'm not sure about it. The only thing about I'm sure is that the guide would be the solution for my problem if I only had a Broadcom card because I've the exactly same problems.

What can I do to discover my wireless drivers and how to install them correctly on Lubuntu to make wifi work?

I'm a user with no advanced knowledge in Linux, so I would need clear explanations on how to make, compile, etc.

Result of

```
$ lspci -knn | grep net -A2

00:14.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP200 3COM 3C920B Ethernet Controller [1002:4342]
00:14.5 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP150 AC'97 Audio Controller [1002:4341] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] IXP150 AC'97 Audio Controller [1025:0065]
--
02:02.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: InProComm Inc. IPN 2220 802.11g [17fe:2220]
    Subsystem: AMBIT Microsystem Corp. T60N871 802.11g Mini PCI Wireless Adapter [1468:0305]
02:03.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8100/8101L/8139 PCI Fast Ethernet Adapter [10ec:8139] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] RTL-8100/8101L/8139 PCI Fast Ethernet Adapter [1025:0036]
    Kernel driver in use: 8139too
    Kernel modules: 8139cp, 8139too
```

Result of

```
lspci -knn | grep Ethernet -A2

00:14.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP200 3COM 3C920B Ethernet Controller [1002:4342]
00:14.5 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP150 AC'97 Audio Controller [1002:4341] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] IXP150 AC'97 Audio Controller [1025:0065]
--
02:02.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: InProComm Inc. IPN 2220 802.11g [17fe:2220]
    Subsystem: AMBIT Microsystem Corp. T60N871 802.11g Mini PCI Wireless Adapter [1468:0305]
02:03.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8100/8101L/8139 PCI Fast Ethernet Adapter [10ec:8139] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] RTL-8100/8101L/8139 PCI Fast Ethernet Adapter [1025:0036]
    Kernel driver in use: 8139too
    Kernel modules: 8139cp, 8139too
```

Result of

```
lspci; lsusb
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS300 Host Bridge (rev 02)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS300 AGP Bridge
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] OHCI USB Controller #1 (rev 01)
00:13.1 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] OHCI USB Controller #2 (rev 01)
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] EHCI USB Controller (rev 01)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SMBus (rev 1a)
00:14.1 IDE interface: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Dual Channel Bus Master PCI IDE Controller
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 434c
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP200 3COM 3C920B Ethernet Controller
00:14.5 Multimedia audio controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP150 AC'97 Audio Controller (rev 01)
00:14.6 Modem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP AC'97 Modem (rev 01)
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS300M [Mobility Radeon 9100 IGP]
02:02.0 Ethernet controller: InProComm Inc. IPN 2220 802.11g
02:03.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8100/8101L/8139 PCI Fast Ethernet Adapter (rev 10)
02:04.0 CardBus bridge: ENE Technology Inc CB1410 Cardbus Controller (rev 01)
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 0bb4:0004 HTC (High Tech Computer Corp.) 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0f62:1001 Acrox Technologies Co., Ltd Targus Mini Trackball Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Comment: Hi Mrfede 14 and Welcome to askUbuntu!  First we have to identify your net-card and your kernel driver and modules. Therefore add the output of the following command to your post: `lspci -knn | grep net -A2`

Comment: edited my first post with all the information

Comment: How are you trying to connect or search for your wireless networks

Comment: Note: You probably have a network manager and the correct adapters for your PCI, you just need to figure out which one you have and which one you want to activate. Gnome network manager has the icon applet, but WPA is usually the default network manager for most Linux machines and doesn't come with a notification icon, can you show us what sudo systemctl  --status-all says, it's been awhile since I've used linux, it may be --status=all or --status all

Comment: add the command `lspci -knn | grep Ethernet -A2` to your post

Comment: Everyone gives wrong command that don't show wireless devices. The correct one is `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` @Mrfede14 please add output of this command.

Comment: @abu_bua `grep net` and `grep Ethernet` are wrong. We are searching for `Network`, so we need `grep Net`.

Comment: @Pilot6 i'm gonna update it in a minute my pc is so shit that is just turning down on his own

Comment: @Pilot6 there is no output to that command

Comment: @Mrfede14 OK, then post output of `lspci; lsusb`. This will list all devices.

Comment: @hellomoto it says unrecognized option

Comment: The device is `Ethernet controller: InProComm Inc. IPN 2220 802.11g`.

Comment: This is a rare case when `ndiswrapper` can be used. See https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2049417.html `ndiswrapper` is available from official repos. You will need to install WinXP driver using it.

Comment: I've already installed XP, I've got two partitions. Now I'm trying to understand something about ndiswrapper.

Comment: I am writing an answer, it will not be a stop-by-step, but it should guide you.

Comment: sudo systemctl list-unit-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very old device. You can install Windows XP drivers using `ndiswrapper`.

First install `ndiswrapper` by running

```
sudo apt install ndiswrapper ndisgtk
```

Then download Windows XP drivers and install it using `ndiswrapper` CLI, or `ndisgtk` GUI.

See [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper).

Read starting with p. 3.6.

Start `ndisgtk`,  click on System | Administration | Windows wireless drivers and follow the instructions on-screen.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80230/discussion-on-answer-by-pilot6-wifi-issues-on-lubuntu).